# Onedrive synce issue using Power Query Editor to update download source

Tags: powerquery

I am trying to update my link to pull from my own One Drive account. I tried opening the sheet online and copying the source, and I tried copying the share link and posting it. I am still unable to make it work without getting the HTML error shown.

[image]

```
= Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents("https://onedrive.live.com/download?&resid=7BA5E7B92829DE18!1263"), null, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me

```
let Source = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents("https://onedrive.live.com/download?&resid=7BA5E7B92829DE18!1263"), null, true),
Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"ABREV", type text}, {"NICKNAME", type text}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Name", type text}, {"Standard Name", type text}, {"B", type text}, {"T", type text}, {"TEAM", type text}, {"Batting POS", type text}, {"POS", type text}, {"Standard Name_1", type text}, {"T2", type any}, {"Column13", type any}, {"Column14", type any}, {"Column15", type any}, {"Column16", type any}, {"SAVANT Table", type text}, {"Column18", type text}, {"Column19", type any}, {"Column20", type any}, {"Column21", type any}, {"Column22", type text}, {"Column23", type text}, {"Column24", type any}, {"Column25", type any}})
in #"Changed Type"
```